# Convert String to Double with Currency

Tags: ios, currency, nsnumberformatter

```
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter   setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    double value = [[numberFormatter  numberFromString: ProviderTripRate.text] doubleValue];
    [User setDouble:value forKey:@"Trip_Rate"];
NSLog(@"     %@                  %f     " , ProviderTripRate.text  ,   value  );
```

If the data inside  ProviderTripRate.text  is   2.75  then  value is 0       wrong
If the data inside  ProviderTripRate.text  is  $2.75  then  value is 2.75  correct

How do you reliably convert from the string to a double value
NOTE that the text string  may or may NOT have the local currency symbol  ($ as shown above)
but it should always  convert

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSNumber* number = [numberFormatter  numberFromString:ProviderTripRate.text]
if (!number) {
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    number = [numberFormatter  numberFromString:ProviderTripRate.text];
}
double value = [number doubleValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ([providerTripRate.text hasPrefix:@"$"]) {
    // use NSNumberFormatter to obtain the value
} else {
    float theValue = [providerTripRate.text doubleValue];
}
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension String {
/// Creates a Double from the string
///
/// Tries various ways of extracting a number, currently handling the following formats
/// - 1000
/// - 1000.00
/// - 1,000.00
/// - $1,000.00
///
/// - Returns: Double value, or 0.0 if a non numerical String is passed
  func asDouble() -> Double {

    if let double = Double(self) {
        return double
    }

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    if let number = formatter.number(from: self) {
        return number.doubleValue
    }

    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    if let number = formatter.number(from: self) {
        return number.doubleValue
    }

    formatter.currencySymbol = ""
    formatter.internationalCurrencySymbol = ""

    if let number = formatter.number(from: self) {
        return number.doubleValue
    }

    return 0
  }
}
```